# ChDir (Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop") Run-time error '76'

Tags: vba, onedrive

I'm getting Run-time error '76': Path not found in VBA. This used to work for me and the only thing that I changed recently was adding my folders to Onedrive (which I feel it could be the cause).

`ChDir (Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop")`

When I use the Immediate window I can print the path without issue there, however I'm getting my company domain as shown below. I don't understand why is not processed by the macro.
Could someone help guide me the way out of this?

```
print(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop")
C:\Users\myname.DOMAIN\Desktop
```

Comment: What about this? `print("C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop")`

Comment: I can't replicate this. Something else must be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot duplicate the problem on my machine, but you can try this workaround which strips out anything after the [first] period...

```
Dim sProfile As String
Dim vSplit As Variant
sProfile = Environ("USERPROFILE")
vSplit = Split(sProfile, ".")
sProfile = vSplit(0)

MsgBox sProfile & "\Desktop"
```

Comment: Thank you, braX. This actually fixed my issue. The domain was causing the error, and by removing it from the string I was able go through the Run-Time error.